# how to boost my script in fault tolerance ,performance and readability

Tags: bash, linux, shell, script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

# debug
#export PS4='$LINENO + '
#set -x

# description : #TODO
#
#

# PERSONAL FUNCTION HERE
########################
##
#
#TODO
#
##
########################

# help information
myhelp() {
    #TODO
    echo "usage : mksh [options] {files} "
    echo ''
    echo "      -h,--help check for help"
    echo ''
    echo "      -o,--output output file to path"
}
#

# without argument
no_arg() {
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        myhelp
    fi
}
#

# DISPOSAL ARGUMENTS
#####################
##
#
cope_args() {
    #TODO
    echo 'disposal args'
}
#
##
#####################

#  cache arguments
arg_menu() {
    #TODO args varities
    help=
    fault=

    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do

        case "$1" in
        -h | --help)
            _LAST_OPT=-h
            help=true
            shift
            ;;
        #TODO needs options
        *)
            echo "invalid : $_LAST_OPT $1"
            fault=true
            break
            ;;
        esac
        
    done

    if [ "$fault" != "true" ]; then
        if [ "$help" == "true" ]; then
            myhelp
        else
            cope_args #TODO need args
        fi
    fi
}
#

# main
main() {
    no_arg "$@"
    arg_menu "$@"
}
#

main "$@"
```

i want to write a script template , but i didnt have good idea,i just add a parameter interpreter and cut script into many modules,but i dont know how to improve

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the **title** to simply [**summarise the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 1):

Summary: this is not a good Code Review submission.

It is marginally [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask),
due to non-existent / hypothetical code.
It is a tool looking for a problem,
rather than a concrete solution to a problem.

Is the *code* bad?
No, not really, it is perfectly serviceable.
The trouble starts with the problem statement you posed for yourself.
You could instead have waited for real problems to arise in your code,
then worry about
[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)ing things up.

Advice to improve:
Recommend you write a couple of scripts that actually do
something useful that you care about, then come back and refactor them.
You will notice trends and patterns that help you decide
what should be extracted as utility code versus what is
properly part of each application's code.

It's not clear that "I want to write a **template**" is the
appropriate goal, as that tends to take us down copy-pasta rabbit holes.
You might be better off pasting `source utility.sh` near the top
of each application script, and defining utility functions **once** in there,
for better maintainability.

---

## functions

You are using bash functions.
Good job, keep it up!

These are good calls:

```
    no_arg "$@"
    arg_menu "$@"
```

They are appropriately quoted,
and we're obeying the `$@` vs. `$*` distinction
to preserve SPACE embedded within an argument.
Not sure if you ran the
[shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net)
linter against this, but you definitely
should prior to a commit. (I noticed no issues.)

What's missing is a comment near top of each
function explaining what parameters it accepts.
Now, these are generic ARGV cracking functions
so maybe it's nice enough as-is.
But since bash doesn't give us much help
in naming the input parameters, it's really
on you the author to shoulder that documentation
burden at the top.
Sometimes we do that as comments, sometimes we
will use stylized assignments such as this:

```
report() {
    out_dir="$1"
    max_size="$2"
    ...
}
```

or with defaulting:

```
report() {
    out_dir="${1:-/tmp}"
    max_size="${2:-300}"
    ...
}
```

It's customary to not verify whether caller passed a spurious `$3` arg --
that's just a rough edge of bash functions.

---

## cracking argv

Your `while [[ $# -gt 0 ]];` loop seems competent enough.
It appears to be much of the motivation for templating
in the first place, and I find not a lot of strong motivation there.
It should be enough to consult an
[example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9274633)
each time you encounter such a problem.

Handling fancy options in bash always feels to me like
there's too many fiddly bits we must always get right,
such as `shift; break`.
For example your `--help` stanza is nice enough and
strictly speaking it doesn't *have* to `break`,
but stylistically that would be a good pattern
for each stanza to finish with.

I see some trivial naming nits.
You might rename to `my_help` for
`_` underscore-between-words consistency with e.g. `no_args`.
Renaming to the slightly longer but
more grammatical `cope_with_args` wouldn't hurt.
Or perhaps `parse_args`.

---

## language

You chose bash.
Ok. It's Turing complete, and much
[nicer](https://harmful.cat-v.org/software/csh)
than some alternatives.

Specifically for cracking argv, frankly it's just not great.
And it's not like that's the interesting part of writing software.
There's actual application logic you should be getting to.

So, you might consider writing in the python scripting language instead:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from pathlib import Path
import os
import typer


def report(out_dir: Path = "/tmp", max_size: int = 200):
    os.chdir(out_dir)
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    typer.run(report)
```

You get `--help` "for free":

```
$ report.py --out-dir /var/tmp --max-size=400
$
$ report.py --help
                                                                                                                                                                        
 Usage: report.py [OPTIONS]                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                        
╭─ Options ──────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ --out-dir         PATH     [default: /tmp]                                                                                                                           │
│ --max-size        INTEGER  [default: 200]                                                                                                                            │
│ --help                     Show this message and exit.                                                                                                               
╰──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

---

## ASCII art

My advice on "#######" is: don't do it.

Organizing your code with clear identifiers and
sufficient vertical whitespace should suffice.
In bash or in any language.

---

## error checking

I notice `set -x` at top, which can certainly be helpful.
Keep in mind that you don't even need to edit source to accomplish that.
You can simply invoke as `$ bash -x the_script.sh` for a debug run.

Some languages started out permissive and then retain that for
back-compatibililty, so for example a perl script will often
lock things down a bit with `use strict;`.

It's a good idea to start each bash script with

```
set -e -u -o pipefail
```

The `-e` causes errors (e.g. from `ls /non/existant`) to exit the script
immediately, and option `pipefail` has the same effect for commands
in the middle of a `|` pipeline.

The `-u` causes undefined (`$foo`) variables to error rather
than return an empty string.

Clearly these change interpreter behavior.
They are designed to help you write in a more conservative dialect,
displaying helpful diagnostics when something unexpected may have happened.
A single `set` line at top of `utility.sh` would suffice,
if your application scripts all `source` that central file.

Comment: thank for your valuable advice,which is very helpful to me as a newbie